# VBA : Loop until a random row is not hidden

Tags: excel, vba

We are trying this trick for a while !
We have a range of 'x' rows, and we would like to make a random sample of 35 rows by hiding all others.
The difficult mission for us is to make all random row unique (to avoid hiding a row already hide).
For that, we tried to make a loop, with a check if the row is already hide.
We tried to make this code, but it's not working :

```
    Function randSample(Rg As Range) As Range

    Set randSample = Rg.Rows(Int(Rnd * Rg.Rows.Count) + 1)
    
End Function
```

```
Sub sampling()

    Dim N As Long, i As Integer, Raw As Range, myRange As Range, sampleRangeCount As Long
    N = Cells(12, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
    Set myRange = Range("A12:AW" & N)
    
    sampleRangeCount = myRange.Rows.Count - 35
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Randomize
    
    For i = 1 To sampleRangeCount
        Do
            Set Raw = randSample(myRange)
        Loop Until Raw.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Raw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Could you help us for that? Where are we wrong?

Thank you a lot!
Kevin

Comment: Hi.  Use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` for your selection range.  Something like `Range("A12:AW" & N).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you !